# Which 3307 Arch 1 x 6 x 2 is correct for 10225 R2D2 Set? "Thick Top with Reinforced Underside" or "Thin Top without Reinforced Underside"

Tags: piece-information

BrickLink shows that the 10225 R2 D2 set contains 3307 Arch 1 x 6 x 2 "Thick Top With Reinforced Underside", but I purchased that set and mine contains the newer "12939" variation which is described as "Thin Top without Reinforced Underside". Does anyone know which is the correct ORIGINAL arch variation contained in this set? And when did the change take place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my R2D2 at launch in 2012 for the May the 4th celebrations through the Dutch Lego@home web shop. This set contains the old 3307 part.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for sharing your experience. I was wondering, because I bought one off EBay last fall, and it was new and sealed, but I was concerned because my arches were not 3307's, even though the bags were sealed, it just made me suspicious, but now I see that it is perfectly possible to have the 12939 arch too...

Answer (score 2):

I cannot give you the definite answer, but LEGO changed the design of the "Brick, Arch 1 x 6 x 2" two times over the last 6 years. The original version is 3307 which was in production/circulation until 2014. It then produced 12939 which entered production/circulation in 2010 and is still out there in new sets, however, in 2014 LEGO started producing yet another design numbered 15254.

Since 10225 R2D2 was produced for about 2.5 years from 2012 to 2014, it fell right smack in the middle of the change-over between these 3 molds. So per set it really depended on what mold had been printed and was sitting in the supply for the given production facility - some sets will have gotten 3307, other sets 12939 and even some late sets will have gotten 15254. For LEGO there is no difference in these parts and they will have been substituted.

Bricklink indeed mentions 3307, but has 12939 listed as alternate, so it recognizes both came in this set. Brickset has both 12929 and 15254 as parts for this set, and Rebrickable has 3307. Finally, BrickOwl is missing this piece from its inventory altogether.

Comment: See here http://www.newelementary.com/2015/11/bow-window-3307-15254-12939difference-lego-arch.html for more details about the three arches 3307, 12939 and 15254 that are not always interchangeable!

Comment: @Philo that is a great article - perfectly explains the whole 3307-12939-15254 switchover. So 15254 is the final design, with R2D2 falling right in the middle of the 3307-12939 switchover, but too early to have the "rectified" 15254. Thanks!

Comment: This was a great informative answer, thank you so much! I'm impressed. I just discovered this website, and, holy cow, how awesome it is because of the knowledge of people like yourself!

Comment: @Sharkfin182: You're welcome. If you think my submission answered your question, feel free to use the checkmark to indicate your acceptance as "the" answer.

Comment: @Philo: Thank you as well, I didn't at first see the difference between "Phil" and "Philo" in these answers! Thanks for the article that went along with Phil B.'s answer, I appreciate you knowledgeable ones!